# showing part of xml response in different DIV tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a AJAX response which looks like this

```
<XML>
  <request>
    <!-- some xml data related to request -->
  </request>
  <response>
    <!-- some xml data related to response -->
  </response>
</XML>
```

My requirement is to display whole xml under  node in a DIV with id=requestDIV and display xml under response in another DIV say id=responseDIV.

I am able to get the XML and display XML as it is using this code

> ```
>       success: function(xml, status, xhr){
>           alert(xhr.responseText);
> ```

My question is how do you select part of the xml using JQUERY?

This is the HTML code

```
<div id="requestDIV">
    <textarea id="requestArea" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>  
    <div id="responseDIV">
    <textarea id="responseArea" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since a simple google search answers your question, let me hit you up with a link :)
http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/

All you need is in that tutorial, better explained than i could.

Comment: Thanks SAM, that was the first page I found when I queried for xml parsing. My problem is to show the whole xml as it is under the <request> and <response> tags.

Comment: I think now i understood your problem, i will do this tomorrow morning at work ;) (~12hrs from now - in case no one got you a working reply by that time)

Comment: Hey, sry for the delay. However i didn't find anything. As it appears to me, XML-content returned via ajax/get is only able to be accessed through dom-traversing functions. Getting a "raw text content" is no option in those ones.
My assumption would be you'd have to get a raw text-content returned and then use basic javascript to "cut" the specified area you want :(

Comment: Hey Sam, Thanks for the response.. Yes I tried to use the XML getElementsByTagName to get hold of the XML node.. Do you think there is a XML node to text kind of method?

Comment: Well it is not a clean method, but if i call the file "test.php" (which returns a xml) then it is interpret by jquery as text, i then was able to do `$(response).find('request').html()` which returned raw content of the respone innerHtml

Comment: Sam, Well thanks for the tip, it is working fine.. I am putting it in the solution to this problem.

Comment: Sam, this doesn't work in IE6.. it just gets the text data..is there another method???

Comment: Who do you develop for? We're reaching 2012 and i STRONGLY encourage everyone to stop supporting IE6 - that browser is only used at very old PCs and at companies that are not aware of new technology. So think for yourself if you REALLY do need IE6 support ;)
(Read: i don't know of any IE6 support regarding jQuery in that matter)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do something like ...

```
$("#requestArea").val($(xml).find("request").text());
$("#responseArea").val($(xml).find("response").text());
```

For your reading pleasure http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/

Comment: That query will get only the text contents.. for example if xml is <request><a>some data a</a><b>some data b</b></request> it will get only some data a,some data b.. I want to display the whole xml <a>some data a</a><b>some data b</b> The link you posted is awesome and I am able to parse the xml, however my question is to show the raw xml not just the values

Comment: oh then instead of using .text() use .html()

Answer (score 0):

As per Sam's idea I resolved the issue by using the responseText and searching for the tag and retrieving the innerHTML like this

```
success: function(xml, status, xhr){
     $("#requestArea").val($(xhr.responseText).find("request").html());
     $("#responseArea").val($(xhr.responseText).find("response").html());
}
```

Comment: This solution works in Firefox, Chrome.. However is not working in IE6